# How to enable contextmenu click on disabled select box

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to call a function on right click on the select box which has disabled attribute. but i am unable to call a function.if i remove disabled attribute, then the right click is working.

```js
function hello() {
  alert('clicked');
  window.event.returnValue = false;
}
```

```css
#testSelect {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<select id="testSelect" oncontextmenu="hello()" disabled="true">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Mouse clicks on `disabled` elements will not be fired. This is why your Handler does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to trigger any mouse event on a `disabled` select.

**BUT** I added a dirty trick that uses a div to simulate the effect :

Put a `div` after your select, position it on top of your select and give it a `display: none`.

Add the CSS rule `.yourSelect:disabled + .yourDiv{display: block;}` to put the new div on top of your select.

You will then be able to catch mouse events on that div.

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).on('contextmenu','.dirty-hack', e => {
  alert('clicked');
  return false;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#testSelect {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

div.dirty-hack {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

#testSelect:disabled+.dirty-hack {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="testSelect" disabled="true">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
<div class="dirty-hack"></div>
```

Comment: this is not a solution for the OT (have a look at my duplicate link which has a much better workaround for this problem)

Comment: **1)** Why is it not a solution for OP ? **2)** My take on the issue joins your link, there's almost no difference between them.

Comment: Ofc it is due to your event will be fired if you click anywhere in the document and the question was about "how to handle click events on disabled elements" The green marked answer in the dupe firstly removes the `disabled` attribute

Comment: Forgot the context on my `contextmenu` handler, my bad.

Comment: This will not realy work, since the dirty-hack will not stick to the select input, but to the top of the page.

Comment: @Bellian I specified in my answer that OP has to put the added div on top of his select. Here I used the shortest way to do it in a snippet, only to illustrate.

Comment: @Zenoo I see. My bad. But I prefer elegant solutions without objects floating in the void.

Answer (score 0):

You can just disable interaction with this select if disabled and create a dummy element which will catch the click:

```js
let element = document.getElementById('dummy');
element.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e)=>{
  alert('clicked');
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#testSelect {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

#testSelect:disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<span id="dummy">
  <select id="testSelect" disabled="true">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap it in a tag and call it by using .click() function from jquery. [Click function](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: could you also provide a working example? I don't think that this is possible...

Comment: this is not working: https://jsfiddle.net/eoqawa1q/4/

Comment: wrap it in a span with a id, then select the input to make the changes.

Comment: Note: You'll have to get the span click.

Comment: so update your answer...and this will add a click handler to the `<span>` and **not** to a `disabled` input field. But the way you formulated your answer is simply not working